# Шустрая IDE для web-разработки

Tags: phpstorm, ide, инструменты-разработчика

Пользуюсь phpStorm на неочень мощном ПК. Постарался максимально оптимизировать данную среду под себя (отключил все ненужные службы и прочее), но среда всё равно постоянно притормаживает. Пишу в основном на php, js + вёрстка на html. При этом из прелестей phpStorm использую только быстрый переход в файл с нужным классом (зажатая клавиша CTRL + клик по названию класса в коде) и подключение ранее не подключённого используемого класса в коде (при нажатии ALT+ENTER неиспользуемый класс подключается в раздел "use"). Подскажите, пожалуйста, более шуструю среду разработки с этими двумя функциями. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

По шторму: попробуйте

1 Включить "Power safe mode"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2 Понизить уровень инспектирования
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Этого не делал. Посмотрим как будет сейчас, хотя не думаю что это очень поможет.

Comment: Дополнительно рекомендую попробовать EAP-версию: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/nextversion/ Мы существенно ускорили редактор, почитать об этом можно здесь: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/10/phpstorm-2017-3-eap-173-2941-8/

Answer (score 0):

как по мне Sublime Text 3 лучший. Он и шустрый и функционален, и дизайн найс. Начал кодить с нотпада++, а теперь коло 2-2,5 лет на нём сижу.

Comment: Я пробовал его, но там нет из коробки тех функций которые мне нужны. Возможно они есть отдельными плагинами но я не смог их найти.